Proving a corollary of Trakhtenbrot theorem
In Sets, Logic, Computation, Trakhtenbrot's theorem is stated as follows:

Theorem 15.21 (Trakhtenbrot's Theorem). It is undecidable if an arbitrary sentence of first-order logic has a finite model (i.e., is finitely satisfiable).

and its corollary is:

Corollary 15.22. There can be no derivation system that is sound and complete for finite validity, i.e., a derivation system which has $\vdash B$ iff $\mathcal M\models B$ for every finite structure $\mathcal M$.

I am trying to prove this corollary. In my proof attempt, I will make use of this fact:

Let $B$ be any FOL sentence. The following are equivalent.
(a) $B$ is satisfied in every finite structure
(b) $\lnot B$ is not finitely satisfiable
(c) $\lnot B$ is unsatisfiable
(d) $B$ is valid

and this theorem:

Theorem 15.18. Validity of first-order sentences is semi-decidable: There is a Turing machine $E$, which when started on a tape that contains a sentence $B$ of first-order logic as input, $E$ eventually halts and outputs $1$ iff $B$ is valid, but does not halt otherwise.

My attempt at proof:
Suppose such derivation system exists. By theorem 15.18, there is a Turing machine $E$ that when given a FOL sentence $B$, it halts with $1$ when $B$ is valid, i.e. $B$ is satisfied in every finite structure, otherwise it will run indefinitely. [???] Then finite satisfiability will be decidable, which contradicts with theorem 15.21.
I need help filling in the [???] part.

Suppose for contradiction that we have a derivation system that is sound and complete for finite validity. I will describe an algorithm to decide if an arbitrary $L$-sentence $\varphi$ has a finite model, contradicting Trakhtenbrot's theorem. (Note that $L$ is the finite language consisting of those symbols appearing in $\varphi$.)
The algorithm will carry out two tasks in parallel (interleaving the steps).
Task 1: Begin enumerating the finite $L$-strutures. For each of them, check whether it is a model of $\varphi$. If it is, halt and output "Yes!".
Task 2: Begin enumerating proofs in our derivation system. For each of them, check whether it is a proof of $\lnot\varphi$. If it is, halt and output "No!".
Note that if the algorithm halts and outputs "Yes!", the answer is correct, since it has found a finite model. And if the algorithm halts and outputs "No!", the answer is correct, since it has found a proof of $\lnot \varphi$, and by soundness of our derivation system, $\varphi$ has no finite models. So it remains to verify that the algorithm halts on all inputs.
If $\varphi$ actually has a finite model, then Task 1 will eventually find it, so the algorithm will halt.
If $\varphi$ has no finite model, then $\lnot \varphi$ is valid on finite structures, so by completeness of our derivation system, there is a proof of $\lnot \varphi$. Task 2 will eventually find this proof, so the algorithm will halt.

Thank you for your answer, which clearly explains the idea of the proof and highlights (contrary to my own answer) how the soundness and the completeness of the derivation system are to be used in the argument!

I am merely a dilettante in metalogic, but I believe I see a general idea on how to answer your question, based on the hints given in Problem 15.12 from your reference text. If I am mistaken, with a bit of luck, by Cunningham's law, someone else will come and correct my answer, for everyone's benefit!
First, a comment: I doubt the correctness of the implication '(a) $\Rightarrow$ (d)' in your 'fact'. In other words, (d) 'validity' and (a) 'finite validity' appear to be inequivalent notions. Indeed, a priori at least, an invalid FOL sentence $B$ could be satisfied in every finite structures, in which case it would necessarily fail to be true in some infinite structure. To me, the reality of this possibility is highlighted by the tension that there would be otherwise between the Corollary 15.22  and the 'Soundness and Completeness Theorems of first-order logic' (the latter is essentially the opposite of statement of Corollary 15.22 without the 'finiteness' qualification, so the 'finiteness' condition seems performative).
Back to the subject, the argument I see to deduce Corollary 15.22 from Trakhtenbrot's theorem is based on the hints given in Problem 15.12 of your reference.
Absurd assumption: There is a derivation system $D$ that is sound and complete for finite validity, i.e., we have $\vdash B'$ (with respect to $D$) iff $M \vDash B'$ for all finite structures $M$.
Definition (as used in Trakhtenbrot's theorem = Theorem 15.21): A sentence $B$ is finitely satisfiable if $M \vDash B$ for some finite structure $M$.
Observation: A sentence $B$ satisfies $M \vDash B$ for all finite structures $M$ iff $M \not \vDash \neg B$ for all finite structures $M$ (i.e., iff $\neg B$ is not finitely satisfiable).
Hence the Claim: Either $\neg B$ is finitely satisfiable or $M \vDash B$ for all finite $M$.
Proof of Corollary 15.22:
Step 1: (Rough idea; see Comment (2) below) I expect that the collection of finite structures $M$ can be effectively enumerated. Moreover, given a (finite) sentence $B$ and a finite $M$, one should be able to determine in finite time whether or not $M \vDash B$. So there should exist a Turing machine $E'$ which, given an input $B'$, goes over the collection $\{M\}$ to test whether or not $M \vDash B'$; $E'$ halts on input $B'$ if it comes across a finite $M$ such that $M \vDash B$, in which case $E'$ outputs $1$. For other $B'$, namely those such that $M \not \vDash B'$ for all finite structures $M$,  $E'$ does not halt. In other words, $E'$ shows that testing for the finite satisfiability of $B'$ is a semi-decidable problem.
Step 2: Much as in the proof of Theorem 15.18, all derivations in (the hypothetical system) $D$ could be effectively enumerated, thereby leading to a Turing machine $E''$ which would halt (with output $0$, say) on input $B$ iff $B$ is a theorem in $D$, i.e., iff $\vdash B$ (with respect to $D$). (If $\not \vdash B$, then on input $B$, $E'$ either halt with output $1$ or does not halt; it is not important.) By the absurd assumption, this means that $E'$ halts with output $0$ on $B$ iff $M \vDash B$ for all finite structure $M$.
Step 3: Given any input $B$, we can run in parallel $E'$ on $\neg B$ and $E''$ on input $B$: we halt the run when either $E'$ or $E''$ halts and we take the corresponding output. (By the Church--Turing thesis, this procedure can be implemented via some Turing machine $T$ on input $B$.) By the Claim and by construction, the procedure always halts: the output is $0$ if $M \vDash B$ for all finite $M$ (this only happens if $E''$ halts on $B$ with output $0$) and it is $1$ if $\neg B$ is finitely satisfiable (this happens if $E'$ halts on $\neg B$ or, perhaps, if $E''$ halts on $B$ with output $1$). In other words, $T$ halts on any input $B$, with output $1$ if $\neg B$ is finitely satisfiable and output $0$ if $\neg B$ in not finitely satisfiable.
By the double negation principle, running $T$ on input $\neg B$ instead, this implies that we can decide whether or not a FOL sentence $B$ admits a finite model, but this is in contradiction with Trakhtenbrot's theorem. Hence the derivation system $D$ does not exist. QED
Comments based on John Davies' comments to this answer:
(1) The reference Set, Logic, Computation by Richard Zach uses the expression 'finitely satisfiable' in two different senses: (i) the definition used above is given in the statement of Trakhtenbrot's theorem, and (ii) the definition in the glossary, namely that a set $\Gamma$ of formulas is finitely satisfiable iff every finite $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$ is satisfiable (i.e., iff $M \vDash \Gamma_0$ for some (possibly infinite) structure $M$). Of course, when $\Gamma = \{B\}$ consists of a single sentence B, 'finitely satisfiable in the second sense' merely amounts to 'satisfiable', which is a weaker notion than 'finitely satisfiable in the first sense'.
(2) As a caveat to Step 1, the collection of finite structures is perhaps not countable, hence not "effectively enumerable". Indeed, the FO language may quite well contain (countably) infinitely many constants and predicates and functions, so even considering a single finite domain $|M_n|$ of cardinality $n \in \mathbb{N}$ (we can assume $|M_n| = \{1, \dots, n\}$), there might be uncountably many inequivalent interpretations of the language over $|M_n|$. However, given a single (finite) sentence $B$, it involves only finitely many symbols and it is formed from finitely many atomic formulas usingfinitely many composition rules; so a first stage of the Turing machine $E'$ could be to effectively decompose the sentence $B$ in such a way. Now, given any $|M_n|$, there are only finitely many 'partial' interpretations of $B$ (and of its finitely constituents symbols/formulas) with domain $|M_n|$, so the collection of such 'finite partial interpretations/structures of $B$' is effectively enumerable (and can thus be performed by a Turing machine $E'$). This would salvage Step 1 if we knew that every 'partial finite interpretation of $B$' extends to a finite interpretation of the whole language; I would guess this is indeed the case.

Nice proof! This question is more involved than I thought. The term "finitely satisfiable" was confusing to me. Previous sections of the textbook defined finite satisfiability differently, which makes me think that compactness is involved. Now that I think about it, the definition finite satisfiability I know is defined for a set of sentences $\Gamma$ and in this context, finite satisfiability is defined for a single sentence $B$.

@JohnDavies Good point, that is indeed rather confusing! I edited my answer to stress the two different meanings of 'finitely satisfiable'...

I just reread your proof and I am now suspicious about your claim about the collection of all finite structures can be effectively enumerated. How do you justify that this collection is countable?

@JohnDavies That's another good point! Since I am not well-versed in metalogic, I cannot quite answer your suspicion, but I edited my answer to explain my intuition about how one could perhaps proceed. Hope this help you get on a right track (or that someone else will jump in to answer you properly)!

@JordanPayette After writing my answer, I realized that your answer is basically the same (just less terse). Sorry to duplicate your efforts.

@JohnDavies If $L$ is a finite language, there are only finitely many $L$-structures of size $n$ up to isomorphism, so there are only countably many finite $L$-structures. They are easy to enumerate: assume their domains are initial segments of the natural numbers, and enumerate all possible interpretations of the symbols in the language.

@AlexKruckman So you are saying that the domain of each $L$-structure of size $n$ is a finite subset of natural numbers, and the countability follows from the fact that the set of all finite subsets of size $n$ of natural numbers is countable, right? Why can't their domains be finite subsets of real numbers?

@JohnDavies We only care about enumerating finite structures up to isomorphism. Every structure with $n$ elements is isomorphic to one whose domain is ${0,\dots,n-1}$. Do you agree that you can effectively enumerate (for example) all directed graphs with $3$ vertices up to isomorphism?

@AlexKruckman Sorry, I don't understand what is meant by "enumerating up to isomorphism."

@JohnDavies generating a list of finite $L$-structures such that every finite $L$-structure is isomorphic to some structure in the list.

@AlexKruckman Can you give me an explicit example of how this enumeration works? For a language $L$ consisting of $3$ constant symbols, what are all finite $L$-structures? You said there are only finitely many finite $L$-structures such that they are isomorphic to each other, right?

@JohnDavies Rather than extending this comment thread, why don't you ask a new question about enumerating finite structures?

@AlexKruckman I just did. I also thought I should make a separate post.
